# How to flatten a nested forEach?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following input:

```
 schema: [{
    fields: [{
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      col: 10,
      value: ''
    }, {
      name: 'description',
      type: 'text',
      col: 2,
      value: ''
    }]
  }, {
    fields: [{
      name: 'password',
      type: 'text',
      col: 8,
      value: ''
    }, {
      name: 'confirmPassword',
      type: 'textarea',
      col: 4,
      value: ''
    }]
  }],
```

And I set the `values` of the objects of the nested arrays like this:

```
updateField (name, value) {
  this.schema.forEach((formGroup, index) => {
    formGroup.fields.forEach(field => {
      if (field.name === name) field.value = value
    })
  })
},
```

Is there a way to avoid using two nested `forEach`? (Without using any library like Lodash?)

Comment: Yes, move the anonymous callback outside, declare a named function.

Comment: Do you need the nested arrays? Seems to me if you changed your input format to have a single `fields` array it would be easier to work with. (If you can't change where it's coming from, can you change it before you start working with it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure but there isn't really a benefit to it.

Your current data structures are such that you are required to iterate over each subitem for each item in your array.

If only the appearance of nesting bothers you, you could separate the functions.

```
updateField (name, value) {
  const updateFormGroupField = field => {
     if (field.name === name) field.value = value;
  };

  const updateFormGroup = formGroup => formGroup.forEach(updateFormGroupField);

  this.schema.forEach(updateFormGroup)
}
```

That being said, there isn't really any benefit here other than personal flavor.

Perhaps a better focus would be to see how to reduce the quadratic complexity of these nested operations using a constant access structure like a `Map` or a `Set`

Comment: I see some benefits: the named callback can be reused, tested and properly documented (e.g.JSDoc) (if it were moved to its own declaration outside of updateField).

Comment: Sure. But I don't think that's much applicable for this particular use-case due to its size.

Answer (score 4):

You can flatten your array using reduce and the spread operator to combine your arrays, then forEach over your flat array:

```
updateField (name, value) {
  this.schema
    .reduce((memo, item) => [...memo, ...item.fields], [])
    .forEach(field => {
      if (field.name === name) field.value = value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will update the value in the original array while keeping the structure of the original array intact. That's what I understood the intention of the question to be. However, it can easily be modified to NOT mutate the original array at all, or it can totally mutate the entire array structure. All depends what the desired result is.

Comment: Really? Maybe I'm wrong but my jsfiddle show that there is no change on original array https://jsfiddle.net/vetc7rko/

Comment: You are missing the variables for name and value. This is a method being called with an expected name and value being passed in. Your name is undefined so your if conditional never gets executed to update the name. See my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1paxc4y/1/

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, although this solution solves the problem of nested callbacks, it's significantly worse in terms of complexity. The time complexity here is actually cubic because `...` is a full array iteration each time. This also means that it uses more memory as well since each iteration in reduce creates a new array. That being said, it won't be a real problem if the data size is small, plus it looks more functional and thus more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for..of` loop, object destructuring, `Object.entries()`

```js
const obj = {
  schema: [{
    fields: [{
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      col: 10,
      value: ''
    }, {
      name: 'description',
      type: 'text',
      col: 2,
      value: ''
    }]
  }, {
    fields: [{
      name: 'password',
      type: 'text',
      col: 8,
      value: ''
    }, {
      name: 'confirmPassword',
      type: 'textarea',
      col: 4,
      value: ''
    }]
  }],
  updateField(name, value) {
    for (let [key, {fields}] of Object.entries(this.schema)) {
      for (let [index, {name: _name}] of Object.entries(fields)) {
        if (name === _name) fields[index].value = value;
      }
    }
  }
}

obj.updateField("name", 123);

console.log(obj.schema[0].fields[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest introducing a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Generatoren_und_Iteratoren_in_Firefox-Versionen_vor_26) which facilitates iterating fields:

```
function* fields(schema) {
  for (let group of schema) yield* group.fields;
}

function updateField(name, value) {
  for (let field of fields(schema)) {
    if (field.name === name) field.value = value
  }
}
```